# Do "SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE" and "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" have to be inside of a transaction?

Tags: mysql, select, transactions, sql-update

I'm reading [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) for these commands and am confused. The descriptions for the commands mention transactions:

> SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE sets a shared mode lock on any rows that
>   are read. Other sessions can read the rows, but cannot modify them
>   until your **transaction** commits. If any of these rows were changed by
>   another **transaction** that has not yet committed, your query waits until
>   that **transaction** ends and then uses the latest values.
>
> For index records the search encounters, SELECT ... FOR UPDATE blocks
>   other sessions from doing SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE or from
>   reading in certain **transaction** isolation levels. Consistent reads will
>   ignore any locks set on the records that exist in the read view. (Old
>   versions of a record cannot be locked; they will be reconstructed by
>   applying undo logs on an in-memory copy of the record.)

But then the examples don't show transactions being used. Running a test command such as `select * from users for update;` without a transaction doesn't result in any errors (it works). Does this mean transactions don't have to be used with these commands? If so, is there any advantage to putting these commands inside of a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction ensures that **all** the commands it contains will either run successfully or rollback.

These types of `select` statements affect **other** transactions in other sessions. So basically wrapping these in transactions is only a matter of whether you are selecting the data as part of a larger set of commands.

If you only want to select the data you should either use the shared lock or no lock at all and no need to begin a transaction.

Comment: `These types of select statements affect other transactions in other sessions.` So they don't effect `select` statements outside of transactions?

Comment: Any update you make must happen within a transaction. I don't know for sure whether an individual select statement must require a transaction per se to run in, because there is nothing to rollback, but regardless of that, other select statements will be affected when you establish a shared or an update lock

Answer (score 2):

In InnoDB each query is effectively run in a transaction. If you don't start transaction explicitly (with start transaction or by setting autocommit to off), each transaction is committed after the query run. This means that if you are not in a transaction, the lock acquired with `SELECT ... IN SHARE MODE` will be released as soon as the query is completed. There is nothing that prevents you from doing this, it just doesn't make much sense to use locks outside of a transaction; as these locks are to guarantee that the value you select won't change until a later query you are going to execute (like if you want to insert/update data in one table based on the values in another)